# Laravel how to join all records from join table

Tags: mysql, laravel

In bellow query I'm trying to get records from 'posts' table with related records from 2 other tables: 'polls' and 'comments'.

But query results repeats 1 'post' as many times as many 'comments' belong for 'post'.

For example. If I have post with id=15 and 5 comments belong for this post then as result I have 5 times post id=15 with one different comment.

How to write query to have only 1 uniqe 'posts' with all comments in section 'comments'?

```
DB::table('posts')
        ->join('polls', 'posts.id', '=', 'polls.post_id')
        ->join('comments','posts.id','=', 'comments.post_id')
        ->whereMonth('posts.created_at','=',date('m',strtotime("01-04-2018")))
        ->orderBy('polls.yes', 'desc')->get();
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's how JOINs work. You should take a look at [models and relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: I can't do it. I need to order by polls.

Comment: How would you order posts if a post can have multiple polls?

Comment: Posts has only one related record in polls table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use models and relationships:

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function poll() {
        return $this->hasOne(Poll:class);
    }
}

class Poll extends Model {
    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment:class);
    }
}

class Comment extends Model {}

$posts = Post::whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m', strtotime("01-04-2018")))
    ->with('poll.comments')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('poll.yes');
```